# How to undo action like ctrl+Z in azure data factory

Tags: azure-data-factory, undo

I am new to azure data factory.
By mistake I deleted for-each loop while developing pipeline.
How can I do  undo this ?

Comment: I have never used this before, but have you tried ctrl + Y?  That's a pretty common "redo" shortcut.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your ADF GIT enabled?
for GIT:
Right clicking on a commit, and clicking 'revert commit' reverses the selected change. Push it back to your remote git repository, and refresh your page on ADF to see the changes reflected.

If not, then there is no undo option in ADF
[image]

this would discard all the changes and not the latest one unlike CTRL+Z

Comment: I dont have git enabled. I am new to  adf , just for learning purpose I created a flow. By mistake I deleted for-each loop. The very next moment i wanted to go back as like in windows notepad/doc using ctrl+z.

Comment: But even if git enabled unless we commit we do not get current changes back.

Comment: yes, unfortunately there is no way around. Its either complete revert or  you need to continue as is. NO way just to revert back a single (latest) change